# loopback 127.0.0.1 TCP port 22 (ssh) is not opened

Tags: macos, ssh, loopback, openssh

I am not able to ssh to localhost on a Mac. When I scan the port on 127.0.0.1, it returns nothing - no port is listening. I know the sshd is running since I am able to remote ssh in this machine using its IP address.

So basically, I cannot ping 127.0.0.1, nor ssh 127.0.0.1. And port scan on 127.0.0.1 shows no port 22. The firewall is turned off completely in my test.

What am I missing? really confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://askubuntu.com/questions/636409/error-cant-assign-requested-address-when-ssh-ing-to-remote-server

Comment: Thanks Philippe, I have tried that solution, it does not work. I have updated my findings above.